# Laravel throwing: method paginate does not exist error

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, eloquent

I am trying to use pagination in laravel. so i try to retrieve all the transactions and paginate it. my flow goes like this for your reference view->controller->repository->model .

myrepository:

```
public function getall(){

    $this->transaction = Transaction::all();


    return $this->transaction;

}
```

mycontroller:

```
 public function getall(){   
  $transactions = $this->transaction->getall()->paginate(10);

    //dd($this->transaction);



    return view('transactions', ['transactions' => $transactions]);

}
```

in my app.php under service providers i made sure i have pagination: Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,

but there is no aliases though.
so in my controller i did : use Illuminate\Pagination;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
//in repository
public function getAll($limit)
{
    $this->transaction = Transaction::paginate($limit); //Use paginate here.
     return $this->transaction;
}

//in controller 
public function getall() {
    $transactions = $this->transaction->getall(10);

}
```

Comment: thx bro i used this method...  i see the first 10 successfully... but i dont see the pages in the bottom ??

Comment: It only shows the first 10 because you are pulling 10. You can increase the value to 20 or whatever you want.

Comment: yes i get that... but i do not see the page numbers in my view why?

Comment: Are you using ` {{ $transactions ->links() }}` in your view ?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Remove the `Use Illimunte\Pagination` from your controller. It's already included in Eloquent.

Comment: ! it worked..sorry i made a mistake i types "transaction"  instead of -> {{ $transactions ->links() }}.. thanks a lot buddy! :)

Comment: My pleasure. And dont let anyone force you to mark their answer. The first guy @geckob gave you a good enough answer and you marked it. Mark the answer that helped you instead of someone pushing you.

Comment: alright..cuz all the methods here does work..its just that i didnt wanna be mean after he asked me to mark it ...

Answer (score 5):

It won't work with your way. Because `all` method will give your `Collection`. Paginate function only works on `Eloquent\Builder` or `Eloquent Model`

If you need to paginate all records without condition,

```
\App\Transaction::paginate(10);
```

Comment: \App\User::->paginate(10); should be \App\User::paginate(10);

Answer (score 1):

Add the following function to your repository

#### Repository

```
public function getModel() {
    return new Transaction;
}

public function getAll() {
    return $this->getModel()->all();
}

public function paginate($limit = 15) {
    return $this->getModel()->paginate($limit);
}
```

#### Controller

```
public function getAll() {
    $transaction = $this->transaction->paginate(10);

    return view('transactions', ['transactions' => $transactions]);
}
```

Comment: If so, kindly accept it so that it might be helpful for others ;)

Comment: Paginate function is supported by Laravel by default, there is no need to create a new one. Check @geckob answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to used `orderBy()` and `paginate()`

Used something like this

```
 $transactions = Transaction::all();

 $transactions = Transaction::orderBy('name')->paginate(10);

 return view('index', compact('transactions'));
```